# The graphs of $y=ax$ and $y=\arctan(bx)$ intersect at three distinct points if?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have a question relating to calculus and inverse trigonometric functions. Any help is appreciated.

The question is:

> The graphs of $y=ax$ and $y=\arctan(bx)$ intersect at three distinct points if?
>
> A: $0<b<a$
>
> B: $a<b<0$
>
> C: $a=b$
>
> D: $b<a<0$

The correct answer is D.
Upon inserting the graphs into desmos I can visually see how they intersect at three distinct points but I am struggling to understand why.

Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: These solutions are not going to be elementary, so you're not going to be able to reasonably construct them in terms of $a$ and $b$. Do you know other tools for counting roots, like intermediate value theorem and/or mean value theorem (or Rolle's theorem)?

Comment: The graphs will intersect in three distinct points as long as b< a.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey Thank you! Not sure if the explanation will be too complicated but why is that so?

Comment: @TheoBendit Hmm unfortunately not, closest thing I can think of is to do with polynomial roots, thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: Arctan(bx) is a bounded and stricly decreasing/increasing fct (depends of b)  while ax is a stricly decreasing/increasing function (depends on "a") unbounded

Comment: @George Ivey: That's not correct, take for example $b=-1$ and $a=1$ which only intersects once.

Comment: First thing is that both a and b should be of the same sign for the 3 roots condition to hold ( else there will be only 1 root )..secondly the relation between a and b can be obtained by comparing the slope of both the curves at origin

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(tan^{-1}(bx))|_{x=0} = \bigg[\frac{1}{1+(bx)^2}\cdot b\bigg]\bigg|_{x=0} = b$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dx}(ax)|_{x=0} = a.$$
We want the slope of the tangent line at the origin to be steeper for the arctan function so that the other line intersects it in 3 points instead of 1 (recall the graph of artan is just an infinitely extended, bounded "S" shape).

Comment: Also,we can comment that both a and b are of the same sign for the curves to intersect at three different points

Comment: Don't forget it's a multiple choice question. You only have to select the right answer - not prove anything. Everyone knows that the tangent of a very small angle is equal to the angle itself. (Don't they?) That means the slope of arctan(bx) at the origin is b. Select answer D and on to the next question.